# alertmanager notify specific slack groups based on severity

Tags: prometheus, slack, slack-api, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to set up Prometheus' Alertmanager so that when I get an alert, I check its severity. If it is "warning", I want to send the alert to the "warning" Slack channel. If it is "critical", send it to the "critical" Slack channel. How do I specify this in the alertmanager.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by configuring [matchers](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#matcher) in route:

```yaml
route:
  receiver: 'slack-notifications-criticals'
  routes:
  - matchers:
      - severity = "warning"
    receiver: 'slack-notifications-warnings'
  - matchers:
      - severity = "critical"
    receiver: 'slack-notifications-criticals'
```

And configuring recievers `slack-notifications-warnings` and `slack-notifications-criticals` with corresponding slack channels.

Example of full configuration with different recipients depending on severity can be found [here](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/main/doc/examples/simple.yml).